# Show that that $x^{\varphi(pq)/\gcd(p-1,q-1)}\equiv 1\mod pq$ for all $x\in (\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z)^\times$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes, how could I approach showing that $x^{\varphi(pq)/\gcd(p-1,q-1)}\equiv 1\pmod {pq}$ for all $x\in (\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z)^\times$? I understand that $\varphi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$.

I've shown separately that $x^{1+k\varphi (pq)}\equiv x\pmod {pq}$ for all $k\geq 0$ and I know from Euler's theorem that $x^{\varphi (pq)}\equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$.

Can this be used to show that there is always an element of order $\varphi (pq)/\gcd(p-1,q-1)$ in $(\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z)^\times$? If not why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d=\gcd(p-1,q-1)$. We show that 
$$x^{\varphi(pq)/d}\equiv 1\pmod{p}.$$
The same argument will show that the congruence holds modulo $q$, and therefore modulo $pq$.

Let  $q-1=dw$. Then 
$$\frac{\varphi(pq)}{d}=(p-1)w.$$
So $p-1$ divides $\frac{\varphi(pq)}{d}$, and now the result follows from Fermat's Theorem.

We could have saved a bit of space by noting that $\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{d}$ is the least common *multiple* of $p-1$ and $q-1$.

Comment: Does it help to show my last part, or is it unrelated? (That there must be an element of order $\mathrm{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z})^\times$)

Comment: It is relevant, but the result does not immediately follow. We have shown that the order of any element divides the lcm, but not that there **is** an element of order the lcm. To do that we want to express the lcm as a product $st$ of numbers, where $s$ divides $p-1$, $t$ divides $q-1$ and $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime. The decomposition $(p-1)w$ that we used above is not into relatively prime numbers.

Comment: After some (slightly nontrivial) thought, I found such a factoring by looking at $p-1=\prod _i p_i^{a_i}$ and $q-1=\prod _i p_i^{b_i}$ and making use of the fact that $\mathrm{lcm}(p-1,q-1)=\prod _i p_i^{\max \{a_i,b_i\}}$ so we can choose $s=\prod _{i\in\{ i: a_i\geq b_i\}} p_i^{a_i}$ and $t=\prod _{i\in\{ i: b_i>a_i\}} p_i^{b_i}$. $s$ and $t$ now meet the condition, but why must there now be something of order $st$?

Comment: We know that $p$ and $q$ have primitive roots, that is, elements $a$ and $b$ of full order. And you probably know that if $a$  has order $s$ and $b$  has order $t$ **and** $s$ and $t$ are *relatively prime* then $ab$ has order $st$.

Comment: Ah! I see the construction now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to be certain I understand, the verbose statement is if $a$ has order $s$ mod $p$ and $b$ has order $t$ mod $q$ then $ab$ has order $st$ mod $pq$?

Comment: About your comment just above: Right **except** it is missing a crucial necessary condition that $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Right, great. Thanks again.